# Can I submit an app for ios 4.2.5 and above?

Tags: ios, app-store

How granular can I set my iOS target? Can you go down to the revision number - major.minor.revsion

i.e. can I set it to iOS 4.2.5 so that it is not targeting iPhone 3G's but supports Verizon iOS 4 iPhone 4's? Or do I have to support 4.3 to ignore the iPhone 3G and therefore lose any <5.0 Verizon users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you may only set major and minor release versions as a target - hence e.g. 4.2 or 4.3 but not 4.2.5.

You may however cut out the iPhone 3G by simply building for ARMV7 only. The 3G still runs on the ARM architecture version 6 (ARMV6) based hardware platform.

Comment: I think you're right, setting support for armv7 means that we lose 3G's and old iPod Touches which is really what we want to do. Thanks!